# Sql query to find count with a difference condition and total count in the same query

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift, postgresql-8.4

Here is a sample table I have

```
Logs
user_id, session_id, search_query,  action
1, 100, dog, A
1, 100, dog, B
2, 101, cat, A
3, 102, ball, A
3, 102, ball, B
3, 102, kite, A
4, 103, ball, A
5, 104, cat, A
```

where
miss = for the same user_id and same session id , if action A is not followed by action B its termed a miss.
Note: action B can happen only after action A has happened.

I am able to find the count of misses for each unique search_query across all users and sessions.

```
SELECT l1.search_query, count(l1.*) as misses
FROM logs l1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT NULL FROM logs l2
     WHERE l1.user_id = l2.user_id
     AND l1.session_id = l2.session_id
     AND l1.session_id != ''
     AND l2.action = 'B'
     AND l1.action = 'A')
AND l1.action='A'
AND l1.search_query != ''
GROUP BY v1.search_query
order by misses desc;
```

I am trying to find the value of miss_percentage=(number of misses/total number of rows)*100 for each unique search_query. I couldn't figure out how to find the count with a condition and count without that condition in the same query. Any help would be great.

```
expected output:
cat 100
kite 100
ball 50
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to move the `EXISTS` into the count

```
SELECT l1.search_query, count(case when NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM logs l2
     WHERE l1.user_id = l2.user_id
     AND l1.session_id = l2.session_id
     AND l1.search_query = l2.search_query
     AND l2.action = 'B'
     AND l1.action = 'A') then 1 else null end
)*100.0/count(*) as misses
FROM logs l1
WHERE l1.action='A'
AND l1.search_query != ''
GROUP BY l1.search_query
order by misses desc;
```

This produces the desired results, but also zeros if no misses were found. This can be removed with a `HAVING` clause, or postprocessing.

Note I also added the clause `l1.search_query = l2.search_query` that was missing, since otherwise it was counting kite as succeeded, since there is a row with B in the same session.

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention this before. I am running this query in amazon-redshift table. I get the following error.   `An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
SELECT l1.search_query, count(case when NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM logs l2
     WHERE l1.user_id = l...
ERROR: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error [SQL State=XX000] `

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to use case statements here. If I have understood your problem correctly .. then the solution would be something like this -

```
WITH summary
AS (
    SELECT user_id
        ,session_id
        ,search_query
        ,count(1) AS total_views
        ,sum(CASE 
                WHEN action = 'A'
                    THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END) AS action_a
        ,sum(CASE 
                WHEN action = 'B'
                    THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END) AS action_b
    FROM logs l
    GROUP BY user_id
        ,session_id
        ,search_query
    )
SELECT search_query
    ,(sum(action_a - action_b) / sum(action_a)) * 100 AS miss_percentage
FROM summary
GROUP BY search_query;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can allways create two queries, and combine them into one with a join. Then you can do the calculations in the bridging (or joining) SQL statement.

In MS-SQL compatible SQL this would be:

```
SELECT ActiontypeA,countedA,isNull(countedB,0) as countedB, 
   (countedA-isNull(countedB,0))*100/CountedA as missed
    FROM (SELECT search_query as actionTypeA, count(*) as countedA 
          FROM logs WHERE Action='A' GROUP BY actionType
         ) as TpA
    LEFT JOIN
         (SELECT search_query as actionTypeB, count(*) as countedB 
          FROM logs WHERE Action='B' GROUP BY actionType
         ) as TpB
ON TpA.ActionTypeA = TpB.ActiontypeB
```

The `LEFT JOIN` is required to select all activities (search_query) from the 'A' results, and join them to only those from the 'B' results where a B is available.
Since this is very basic SQL (and well optimized by SQL engines) I'd suggest to prevent `WHERE EXISTS` as much as possible. The `IsNull()` function is an MS-SQL function to force a NULL value into the int(0) value which can be used in a calculation.

Finally you could filter on

```
WHERE missed>0
```

to get the final result.

Comment: If the question is about PostgreSQL, why put an MSSQL solution?

Comment: SQL is quite compatible across engines. This answer is helping with the concept of SQL across systems. I could only test the solution on MS-SQL. I'm not quite happy with the down vote on this one...

Comment: SQL is a standard and MSSQL is well-known for deviating from it, far more than PostgreSQL anyway. The latter does not have the `isNull()` function for the stated purpose, but uses `coalesce()`. And your code has errors in it, whether you run it in PostgreSQL or MSSQL. The downvote is for an inadequate answer.